how to fold switch/case lines (Java code) in IntelliJ (2024.1.4 version)?
So I am looking at some vendor code that uses a switch statement. For whatever reason, the vendor decided to place the all the code inside the "enclosing" case statement, so the code is very long and is hard to read. (I would have at least converted these to individual functions that's called when required)
I'm trying to "fold" the case statements so I can only see the code I'm after BUT IntelliJ only wants to fold at the switch level.
Maybe there's a  setting I need to configure? Thank you.
Thanks
EDIT:
So I selected the case lines I want to fold and go to the option Code => Folding => Collapse

and then this is what I get in IntelliJ (so it collapsed the whole switch statement instead of the case  lines t


Can you demonstrate the desired result by showing original code and the folded code (as text)?

@Sweeper edited my original post. Thanks

Code folding in the manual.

You have to place the cursor inside the block which you want to fold.Then by using the collapse action as shown in the figure will do the job.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
